# Copy a string until character found in Java

Tags: java, string, truncate

Hello I was wandering how can I copy a piece of a String in Java until a character/symbol is found. 
In my case the original string is: `"hello.1234"` and I want only `"hello"`, so that every thing after the symbol `.` is discarded.

Any idea? many thanks

**EDIT:**

solved as follows:

```
String partBeforeFullStop = input.split("\\.")[0];
```

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: What about reading each character until you find `.` ? Or using a function that will cut the String with `.` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`String#indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) and [`String#substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29).

```
String input = "hello.1234";
String output = input.substring(0, input.indexOf('.'));
```

Comment: this thing does the opposite of what I wanted :S

Comment: Use `input.substring(0, input.indexOf('.'));` instead.